# Javascript function not working with certain if/else statements for some reason

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, if-statement

For some odd reason that I can't figure out, the code won't work when I have these if/else statements inside it, it works fine when they aren't there. I assume it's something to do with the condition I've attached to the if/else statements, as when simpler conditions are used it seems all right. Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
    function wordSplit(){
        var sentence = document.getElementById("two").value;
        var userWords=sentence.split(" ");
        while(t<userWords.length){
            alert(userWords[t]);
            t++
        };
        x = 0;
        for (var x = 0; x < userWords.length; x++){
            y = 0;
            for (var y = 0; y < vocab.length; y++){

                if (y<vocab.length) {
                    y++
                };
                else if (vocab[y] == userWords[x]){
                    y = 0;
                    x++
                };
                else if(y<vocab.length) {
                    y++
                };
                else if (y == vocab.length){
                    y = 0;
                };
                else if (y == 0)
                {
                    vocab.push(userWords[x]);
                    x++
                };

            };


        };
    };
```

To reiterate, as far as I can tell the problem is definitely in that if else section, as when it is removed or altered to be a lot simpler, it suddenly works.

Comment: Lose the `;` before `else`. Trivial syntax errors like this can be seen in your browser's web developer tools (typically by pressing F12).

Comment: Note, the second `if (y < vocab.length)` (third `if`) is useless.  It'll never run, even after this code is fixed;  the condition that'd cause it to run was already handled by the first `if`.

Comment: Oh I didn't know about the F12 shortcut, thanks for the info. And I'll remove that third if statement, thanks:)

Answer (score 0):

@DCoder is correct, you need to drop the extra `;`

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="two" value="What the hell is wrong here??" />​
```

JavaScript:

```
wordSplit();

function wordSplit() {
    var vocab = [];
    var sentence = document.getElementById("two").value;
    var userWords = sentence.split(" ");
    var t = 0;
    while (t < userWords.length) {
        alert(userWords[t]);
        t++
    };
    x = 0;
    for (var x = 0; x < userWords.length; x++) {
        y = 0;
        for (var y = 0; y < vocab.length; y++) {

            if (y < vocab.length) {
                y++
            } else if (vocab[y] == userWords[x]) {
                y = 0;
                x++
            } else if (y < vocab.length) {
                y++
            } else if (y == vocab.length) {
                y = 0;
            } else if (y == 0) {
                vocab.push(userWords[x]);
                x++
            }

        }


    }
}​
```

[**Fixed Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/gNFM5/6/)

Comment: Thank you! that works, so the ; was screwing everything up? Thanks so much for the correction:)